# Proof verification: The limit superior of the product of an arbitrary sequence and a convergent sequence

Tags: analysis, solution-verification

> Suppose that $a_n\rightarrow a>0$ and $\lim\sup b_n = b \in \mathbb{R}$. Then
> $$ \lim\sup a_nb_n = ab \mbox{.} $$

**PROOF** Since $a_n\rightarrow a$, $a_n>0$ for all $n$ from some definite index $N$ onward. Give $\epsilon>0$. By definition of $b$, there exists $N_1>N$ such that
$$ a_nb_n < a_n(b+\epsilon) $$
if $n>N_1$. Letting $n\rightarrow\infty$, we have
$$ \limsup a_nb_n \leq a(b+\epsilon) \mbox{.} $$
Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary,
$$ \limsup a_nb_n \leq ab \mbox{.} $$
Observe that the limit superior of any subsequence cannot exceed that of the mother sequence. Again, by definition of $b$, there is a subsequence $\{b_{n_k}\}$ of $\{b_n\}$ for which
$$ b_{n_k} > b-\epsilon \mbox{.} $$
Thus,
$$ a_kb_{n_k} > a_k(b-\epsilon) $$
for $k>N$, so that
$$ \lim\sup a_nb_n \geq a(b-\epsilon) \mbox{.} $$
Hence,
$$ \lim\sup a_nb_n \geq ab \mbox{.} $$
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Is this proof valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second part is not correct. You get $a_{n_k}b_{n_k} >a_{n_k}(b-\epsilon)$. This  gives $a_{n_k}b_{n_k} >(a-\epsilon)(b-\epsilon)$ for $k$ sufficiently large. Now you conclude that $\lim \sup a_nb_n \geq \lim \sup a_{n_k}b_{n_k}\geq (a-\epsilon)(b-\epsilon)$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary this gives $\lim \sup a_nb_n \geq  ab$.